# camel http component is not set the response in the exchange body

Tags: spring-boot, apache-camel, spring-camel

I am using Camel version 3.2.0 and Spring Boot Version 2.2.6.RELEASE .

I am using camel-http component to consume a rest service which return list of product in JSON format.
I am trying to store in csv file.  Because of http response is not set in the out in exchange, the body is empty.

I am using the below route.

```
<route id="getProducts">
    <from uri="quartz://groupName/timerName?cron=0 0/2 * 1/1 * ? *" />
    <setHeader name="CamelHttpMethod">
      <constant>GET</constant>
    </setHeader>
    <to uri="http://localhost:8080/product"></to>
    <log message=" before processor \n Body ${body} \n headers ${headers}"/>
    <!-- <process ref="processor" /> -->
    <log message=" before convert \n Body ${body} \n headers ${headers}"/>
    <marshal>
        <bindy type="Csv"  classType="com.basf.vo.Product"   />
    </marshal>
    <log message=" after convert \n Body ${body}"/>
    <to uri="file:\balachandar\?fileName=abc.csv"/>
    <log message="Products Received \n ============================= \n"/>
</route>


<log message=" before processor \n Body ${body} \n headers ${headers}"/> => It is printing Body {"productId":1,"name":"Pink Ralph Lauren Polo Shirt","category":"Dress"} in the console

<log message=" before convert \n Body ${body} \n headers ${headers}"/>  => It is not printing the body. Body is empty.

I used custom processor to know the body.

public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
    String msg = exchange.getIn().getBody(String.class);
    String msg1 = exchange.getMessage(String.class);
    System.out.println("Rest Response is:->" + msg);   //  Rest Response is:->
    System.out.println("Rest Response is:->" + msg1);  //  Rest Response is:->null

}
```

It is printing the body first time, but not subsequent time through processor or log component.
I am not sure why response is not set in the body.   Please help on this.

Answer (score 2):

The response type is a stream. When you log the response first time you consume that stream and the data is gone. You can either enable [stream caching](https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/stream-caching.html) or convert the stream to a string (`<convertBodyTo type="java.lang.String"/>`) before doing anything else with the message body.

Comment: <to uri="http://localhost:8080/product"></to>
<convertBodyTo type="java.lang.String"/>
<log message=" before processor \n Body ${body} \n headers ${headers}"/>

It is working.

Answer (score 0):

Use exchange.getOut().getBody(String.class) to get response body.

Please refer to the link:
https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/http-component.html#_message_body

Comment: exchange.getOut().getBody(String.class) is deprecated in the latest versions.  It is replaced by exchange.getMessage(String.class);   As mentioned its returning null value.